# Separate Z-stepper E-steps

Tags: marlin

I have three stepper motors each with its own stepper driver. Two of those motors have the same lead screw, while the third has a ball screw.

I need to be able to set the E-steps for the ball screw differently than the two lead screws.

Can this even be done in Marlin 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, It does not appear that any firmware currently available supports this feature, however you can [request the feature on the marlin GitHub repository](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/issues/new?assignees=&labels=T%3A+Feature+Request&template=feature_request.yml&title=%5BFR%5D+%28feature+summary%29)

Comment: I thought as much, I am going to need to get two more lead screws.